# No such file or directory error with Sidekiq on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I'm using the Sidekiq gem to do some background processing involving video files. On my local machine everything works fine but I'm getting the aforementioned error in production. I read about [Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) and sure enough I'd restarted Heroku so that could be the problem? If it is I don't know how to deal with it given that there is already a `tmp` folder in my app's root directory. This is the exact error I'm getting from my worker:

`2015-09-09T21:41:37.859890+00:00 app[worker.1]: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/RackMultipart20150909-3-420sel.mp4`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you uploading the video and then processing it?  Maybe provide a little more info on the video file, where it should reside, and how it got there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot share files between dynos.  You'll need to upload to S3 and pass the S3 link to Sidekiq.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done this and it is error-free but now the process is timing out on Heroku. It has slowed down somewhat on development but at least the job is still being executed. I have changed my web server to Unicorn but that's not helping.