# Why my sidekiq worker doesnot work in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I have csv upload and it works fine in local, but in heroku is giving me the error "no such file or directory" in the worker log. Any idea ? It is because that my heroku is a free account ?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32490336/4330954) and [its answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32491355/4330954). Looks like you already have an answer there...

Comment: You can not upload files to Heroku except temporarily. Maybe configure an S3 account.
https://discussion.heroku.com/t/write-files-in-heroku/565/4
 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3